# Is this possible to generically convert enum of the same type from different classes in java?

Tags: java, generics, methods

I have an external model with about 20 classes, which I have to use, but cannot modify (in code below examples: `FirstExtClass`, `SecondExtClass`). In each of these classes there is an enum, which is its internal class (code below: `TheSameEnum`). I am translating it into my model, in which I want each of these enums to be just one type: `EnumFromMyModel`. I have solved it using many functions, that convert external enums to my enums (2 examples are below, but to completely convert them I need 20 copy-paste methods like below.

I am trying to create one generic function, that would take a class with TheSameEnum as parameter and return EnumFromMyModel (something like third function in code below).

```
private static EnumFromMyModel 
convertFirstEnumFromExternalModelToEnumFromMyModel(FirstExtClass.TheSameEnum input) {
    return input.equals(FirstExtClass.TheSameEnum.FIRST_VALUE) ?
            EnumFromMyModel.FIRST_VALUE :
            EnumFromMyModel.SECOND_VALUE;
}

private static EnumFromMyModel convertSecondEnumFromExternalModelToEnumFromMyModel(SecondExtClass.TheSameEnum input) {
    return input.equals(SecondExtClass.TheSameEnum.FIRST_VALUE) ?
            EnumFromMyModel.FIRST_VALUE :
            EnumFromMyModel.SECOND_VALUE;
}


private static <T> EnumFromMyModel genericConvert(T input) {
    return input.equals(/*????*/) ?
            ScopeUsageLimit.FIRST_VALUE :
            ScopeUsageLimit.SECOND_VALUE;
}
```

My question is: is this possible to create such generic function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some sample code for you. You need `toGeneric` method.

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Generic genericFirst1 = toGeneric(Specialized1.FIRST);
        Generic genericFirst2 = toGeneric(Specialized2.FIRST);
        assert genericFirst1 == genericFirst2;

        Specialized1 specialized1 = toSpecialized(Generic.SECOND, Specialized1.class);
        assert specialized1 == Specialized1.SECOND;
    }

    private static <T extends Enum<?>>T toSpecialized(Generic v, Class<T> specialized1Class) {
        try {
            return (T) specialized1Class.getField(v.name()).get(null);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static Generic toGeneric(Enum<?> e) {
        return Generic.valueOf(e.name());
    }

    enum Generic {
        FIRST, SECOND
    }

    enum Specialized1 {
        FIRST, SECOND
    }

    enum Specialized2 {
        FIRST, SECOND
    }

}
```

Comment: instead of using reflection to get the field, you can also just look up the enum from the string like this: `return Enum.valueOf(specialized1Class, v.name());`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you are looking for something like the below code:

```
private static <T extends Enum> EnumFromMyModel genericConvert(T input) {
    return input.name().equals(/*????*/) ?
            EnumFromMyModel.FIRST_VALUE :
            EnumFromMyModel.SECOND_VALUE;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this *if* the enum value names of your and the external model are equal by converting the external enum to `String` and then converting this string back to your enum like this:

```
private static EnumFromMyModel genericConvert(Enum<?> input) {
  return EnumFromMyModel.valueOf(input.name());
}
```

This will throw an `IllegalArgumentException` in case no matching enum from `EnumFromMyModel` can be found.

Still, i'd rather not use this and create all those 20 methods you mentioned and explicitly convert each enum value in a compile time safe manner. IMHO, the benefit of having compile time safety outweighs the benefit of having to write a little less code.